# Seemingly Simple. Spark AR how do you rotate an object an additional 90 degrees each time you press the button?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, instagram-api, spark-ar-studio

I have a button and a 3d object. I would like the object to rotate 90 degrees smoothly each time i press the button once. So if i press it 4 times it does a full 360 turn. I tried googling for an example but had no luck so far. Working with Patches Spark AR.

I can get it to snap rotate 90 degrees on press ok, but stuck after this,  i need it to accumulate in degrees 90,180,270 smoothly etc on each press. Working progress of layout.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Without animation

The easiest way to do that with patches is to have a `Counter` patch that will increase each time the `Tap` event is triggered.  The counter can take values in a range from 0 to 3 (including both ends).  Then its `Value` is just `Multiplied` by 90 and is sent to the rotation patch of an object that needs to be rotated.  This is done with the `Pack` patch that, in this case, accepts the value for just one rotation axis and the other two are always zeros.  You can adjust it for your own way of rotation.
[image]

#### With animation

Below is one of the solutions how this can be animated.  `Tap` triggers the `Animation` to start immediately, but animation reset and changing the `Counter` happens with the `Delay`, which is the same as the animation duration.  Then, with `Multiply` and `Add` patches we can figure out the **start** and **stop** values that the angle of rotation should take, and feed them to `Transition` patch.  The last `Swizzle` patch can be replaced with `Pack` patch, but swizzle is *probably* a little bit more efficient.

[image]

#### Other Notes

By the way, using custom buttons and other 'self-made' UI elements is not advised by Spark AR official guidelines.

Comment: Thankyou Lev for your response to create an efficient working solution which snaps into place on each press, Do you think its possible to have a smooth or timed transition for every 90 degree rotation? This is the dilemma I cannot overcome yet.

Comment: Thankyou again Lev, this mostly works ok! Its a little buggy on testing, skipping/jumping counts from time to time. That said this is a great starting point and enough to progress with a proof of concept.

Comment: Yes, I've also noticed a skipping bug.. and I'm sure it can be done with scripting much easier! =D